# Show last output of ipywidget Output widget

Tags: jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I am using ipywidget's 'Output' widget.  As text is sent to it, scrollbars appear as the amount exceeds what can be shown.  At that point, only the first lines of text are shown.  Instead, as new text is added, I want it to auto-scroll such that the last line printed is always shown.

The current behavior:
[image]
How can I make the last line of output displayed as it is printed?

Comment: Here there is a related unsolved issue: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2980#issue-708060843

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no general solution to the scroll_to_bottom problem. See: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1815

In the discussion there seems to be a linux specific solution which I cannot verify.

The issue is on the milestone list of ipywidgets https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/milestone/2